# patgen: tex file generation from dictionary

Tags: languages, hyphenation, dictionaries, patgen

I am managing a project where we will need to run `patgen` on a new niche language (a mixture of English and vernacular). I am just wondering if anyone has any advice on generating the patterns.

For instance, should the dictionary format be in a `.txt` file with the word followed by a comma for separation and the hyphenated word or should it just contain the hyphenated word?
And how long will it take?

Comment: there's a pretty rudimentary man page that can be read on a tex live system as `texdoc patgen`